# python generate_signed_query_string blob return wrong query string

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to share a blob in a private Azure blob storage container using Python SDK, below is the code:

```
try:
        accss_plcy = AccessPolicy()
        accss_plcy.start = '2013-03-12'
        accss_plcy.expiry = '2013-03-13'
        accss_plcy.permission = 'r'
        signed_identifier = 'YWJjZGVmZw=='
        sap = SharedAccessPolicy(accss_plcy, signed_identifier)
        qry_str = sas.generate_signed_query_string('picture/xxx.jpg','blob', sap)
    except Exception as ex:
        abort(400, 'Download blob fail %s'%ex)
    return sas._convert_query_string(qry_str)
```

Below is the query string return :

```
st=2013-03-12&se=2013-03-13&sp=r&resource=blob&sig=FI88prUINf58Seg5Nwo6Uj5RP9FxXGZBBSKi7pybmeQ=&
```

You may notice that `resource=blob`, but it should return `sr=b`.

How should I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the SDK. Since the code for Azure SDK is open source, you could possibly download the code and make change to this file: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/src/azure/storage/sharedaccesssignature.py. Looking at the source code in that file, you would need to change the following line of code (line 129):

```
convert_str += SIGNED_RESOURCE_TYPE + '=' + query_string[SIGNED_RESOURCE] + '&'
```

to

```
convert_str += SIGNED_RESOURCE + '=' + query_string[SIGNED_RESOURCE] + '&'
```

Also I noticed that you're passing `blob` as the resource type in your code above:

```
qry_str = sas.generate_signed_query_string('picture/xxx.jpg','blob', sap)
```

You would need to pass 'b' instead of 'blob'

```
qry_str = sas.generate_signed_query_string('picture/xxx.jpg','b', sap)
```

I think that should do the trick. Also please ensure that you submit a bug on Github so that the team responsible for maintaining the code can fix it.